# Android wifi geofence/background location querying

Tags: android, geofencing

I'm writing an Android app (not a novel one), that will turn off/on the user's wifi based on their location. It will get the approximate location using the network's location. I'm basically using Google maps to save the geofences they create to my database. I'm curious what's the best approach in terms of insuring the app doesn't have to be in the foreground for it to work correctly.

Should I use `addProximityAlert` or something different? Considering I'm creating multiple geofences and the user could potentially have 10 set up, I fear using different proximity listeners for each geofence. Instead, it would seem more power efficient to query for location every 15 minutes or so and then let the app decide if it's in reasonable range of any of those geofences.

Let me know, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the brand new GeoFence feature Google just released. It supports API 8+.
The Class reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html

Guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Edit:
There is a mention on GeoFences limit in LocationStatusCodes:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationStatusCodes.html#GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES

Comment: Well an entire final project with many hours spent working later, it's cooked into Android. Just my luck :) Thanks for the advice though, may rewrite it with this.

Comment: do you have any reference for the limit of 100 geofences? I was not able to find any information or clue on that limitation...

Comment: @usb79 it was mentioned at Google I/O although the developers said there would be a clarification about the limit of Geofences. They may have removed it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @usb79 I found some reference to the 100 geofence limit. Its been added to the answer.

Comment: @Ejmedina thx! In my eyes, this is really a shame for google.

Comment: Google's geofence is based on GMS. Does that mean it's impossible to use geofence in Android devices without GMS?

Answer (score 6):

here is the sample code i write, it's worked fine for me

```
public class LocationClientService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener {

private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private List<Geofence> mGeofenceLists = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Geofence geofence1 = new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId("your target place")
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setCircularRegion(0.0, 0.0, 2000.0f)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .build();

    mGeofenceLists.add(geofence1);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationClient.addGeofences(mGeofenceLists, getPendingIntent(), this);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onAddGeofencesResult(int i, String[] strings) {
    if (LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS == i) {
        //todo check geofence status
    } else {
    }
}
```

}

then write a IntentService to recieve geofence enter or exit:

```
public class TransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE = "ReceiveTransitionsIntentService";

    public TransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE);
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
        //todo error process
    } else {
        int transitionType = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
        if (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            List<Geofence> triggerList = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
            for (Geofence geofence : triggerList) {
                Log.i("test", "triggered Id " + geofence.getRequestId());
            }
        }
        generateNotification(transitionType);
    }
}

    private void generateNotification(int type) {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/chenjishi/android_location_demo  this is a demo for   how to use the new location api provided by android, include sample code for Fused location, Geofencing and Activity recognition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested you can check out this IO session to see an overview of features and limits:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc
Geofencing is around 23:15

Comment: @Raul I found the video on youtube and updated the link.